# GCM message to all users (without topics)

Tags: node.js, performance, api, google-cloud-messaging

**I have the following dilemma:**

- I need to send a heartbeat message every 5 minutes (or less) to all users of my app
- I thought about topic messaging, but the 1 million subscriber limit is not acceptable for my application
- So: the only possibility left is sending out the message in batches of 1000
- This is really resource intensive

**Now my question:**
How can I make this process of batching and sending really efficient? Is there a good solution already made, preferably in node.js?

Thank you,
Sebastian

Comment: @ujwaldhakal The point is: I need to send a _heartbeat_ message, which is never going to be displayed to the user. It simply serves the purpose of keeping the client alive.

Comment: @Serbastian the cllient is already connects to the node js socket where client hits tha page why need such msgs?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal Nope, I need **Google Cloud Messaging** messages to a mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use XMPP, instead of HTTP.

As google [says](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs), it is less resource intensive in respect to HTTP:

> The asynchronous nature of XMPP allows you to send more messages with
>   fewer resources.

Also you can have 1000 similtanouis connection per app (sender ID):

> For each sender ID, GCM allows 1000 connections in parallel.

Also there exists a [node-xmpp](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp) solution available for that.

Comment: Thank you. So basically the limit is the same for XMPP, but the protocol is simply more efficient and thus faster, right?

Comment: @SebastianWalker It's not actually the same, because you have to send 1000 different requests in XMPP, while sending only 1 request in HTTP. But as Google says, it needs fewer resources.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking, because you can send a message to 1000 recipients at a time. Mixed that up.